# using exec to sort a text file in c

Tags: c, sorting, exec, fork

I have a text file full of records (output.txt) and I want to sort every record by its id. After the sorting the sorted records are written into a new file (sorted.txt).

To do that I am using bash's command "sort" via an execl() function. To check the validity of my sort command, I wrote the same command straight into the bash and the result is the expected one. But when I try to use the execl command through my C program, most of the time the answer will be that there is not a file /usr/bin/sort (I am using Mac OSX) or no error message will be thrown but nevertheless nothing happens...
What I am using is this:

```
execl("/usr/bin/sort", "usr/bin/sort", "-n","-k", "1", "-u", "output.txt", ">", "sorted.txt", (char*)NULL);
```

or this

```
execl("/usr/bin/sort", "usr/bin/sort", "-n","-k", "1", "-u", "-o", "sorted.txt", "output.txt", (char*)NULL);
```

I know that both of these 2 sort commands are correct when I m using them in the bash. What happens to C?
Thnx all in advance!

Comment: Why don't you let your own program do the sorting? It's far more robust than depending on some external binary that the user might or might not have, which might or might not support the flags that you are passing it.

Comment: @Thomas: Alternatively...if one is going to put in a dependency on the "UNIX toolbox" metaphor, it might be better to rethink and define the behavior of your program for *unsorted* input...then fit into the toolchain with the person scripting deciding to sort their input or not.  *"Write programs that do one thing and do it well"*  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy

Comment: @Thomas well it's kind of an exercise at my OS courses so I cant do much about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output redirection (`> somefile.txt`) is a feature of the shell, not the sort program (which AFAIK is not a bash built-in).
The `exec` family of functions doesn't start the shell, only the program you've specified.

If you don't know the path to the program, you can use the functions with `p` in their names (`execlp` in your case, I think) and just give them `"sort"` as program name, they'll search for it in $PATH like bash does.

Comment: I followed your advice and ended up to this: 'execlp("sort", "-n","-k", "1", "-u", "-o", "sorted.txt", "output.txt", (char*)NULL);'. The result is that I dont get any error, I have my sorted.txt file created, but nothing is in there...

Comment: @kostia I'm not an expert on `sort`, but isn't `-k 1` the default behavior anyway?

Comment: You are probably right but that's not an issue... I run this command in terminal and I got the right results...

Comment: Well I've figured out what was wrong... I was attempting to read from output.txt but I forgot to close it after writing in it...

Comment: Nevertheless, I believe that your answer (the part with ">") is somehow helpful to others too!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try `system("sort output.txt > sorted.txt")`. The `system` function's behaviour is implementation dependent though on linux it basically spawns a new shell which executes the command passed to it.  `system(ARG)` is equivalent to `sh -c ARG`.  The redirection will work if the shell supports it in your system's implementation of  the `system` function.

Comment: Mac OSX 10.6 it is with GCC 4.2.1 (darwin)